# How to decorate event in WinRT class?

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime

In classic class library, I can do:

```
public event EventHandler Changed
{
  add { decorated.Changed += value; }
  remove { decorated.Changed -= value; }
}
```

Now, if I work with winRT classes, compiler complains about such code. I managed to patch 'add', but stuck with remove:

```
public event EventHandler Changed
{
  add { return decorated.Changed += value; }
  remove { decorated.Changed -= value; }
}
```

How should I implement remove part?

Comment: What is the compiler's complaint?

Comment: It says it "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationToken' to 'System.EventHandler<Windows.A.B.CustomEventArgs>'"

Comment: Yes, this changed in WinRT, EventRegistrationToken is the essential type, it stores the cookie for the event.  I can only find a C++/CX example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755799%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationTokenTable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138412(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Stores mappings between delegates and event tokens, to support the implementation of a Windows Runtime event in managed code.
>
> Use this type when you need to manage the addition and removal of events manually.
>
> An instance of this table stores the delegates that represent the event handlers that have been added to an event. To raise the event, invoke the delegate that is returned by the `InvocationList` property, if it is not `null`. An instance of this table is required for each event.

For example,

```
private EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<Object>> _changed
     = new EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<Object>>();

public event EventHandler<Object> Changed
{
    add    { return _changed.AddEventHandler(value); }
    remove { _changed.RemoveEventHandler(value);     }
}
```

Comment: Yes - This is how I implement my custom event, but it does not handle decorating events from other classes. If I should use associated EventRegistrationTokenTable instance, I need to have access to it. It is inside decorated class. What if decorated class does not expose it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a fake backing event and lookup dictionary for storing the information you need to forward the event.  For example:

```
public event EventHandler<Object> Changed
{
  add
  {
    // get fake token so that we can return something and/or unsubscribe
    EventRegistrationToken token = _changed.AddEventHandler(value);
    // subscribe and store the token-handler pair
    _otherClass.Event += value;
    _dictionary[token] = value;
    return token;
  }
  remove
  {
    // recall value and remove from dictionary
    _otherClass.Event -= _dictionary[value];
    _dictionary.Remove(value);
    // remove it from the "fake" event
    _changed.RemoveEventHandler(value);
  }
}

private EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<Object>> _changed;
private Dictionary<EventRegistrationToken, EventHandler<Object>> _dictionary;
```

Alternatively, it may be easier to subscribe to the CLR event from the WinRT class, and simply forward the CLR event to the WinRT subscribers; more or less reversing the flow from what you asked:

```
public WinRtObject()
{
  _otherClass.Event += (sender, o) => OnChanged(o);
}

public event EventHandler<Object> Changed;

private void OnChanged(object e)
{
  EventHandler<object> handler = Changed;
  if (handler != null)
    handler(this, e);
}
```